# control bluetooth headset through computer

Tags: java, bluetooth, volume, headset

I've been searching everywhere, but have not been able to find the answer - perhaps I've just been using the wrong search terms, but I was wondering if anyone knows if there's a way to control the volume on a bluetooth headset automatically?  I was looking into using Java, since they have a stack defined already, but am open to anything that might work.  If it could be integrated with Matlab as well, that would be even better.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Entirely depends on the headset make and model.

Comment: Must be a real geek to control headphones with Matlab :)